# Everything seems well but still, dojox/calendar/Calendar doesn't shows the items

Tags: calendar, dojo

I'm using "dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore" look's:
    {"identifier": "id",
    "items": [
        {"id":"3","date_start":"02/11/2012","date_end":"02/11/2012","time_end":"11:00:00","time_start":"09:00:00","type":"visit","title":"Some Title One","week_day":"5","start_hour":"9","start_minute":"0","duration":"120","day_long":"false"},
        {"id":"4","date_start":"23/10/2012","date_end":"05/11/2012","time_end":"12:15:00","time_start":"10:15:00","type":"visit","title":"Some Title Two","week_day":"2","start_hour":"10","start_minute":"15","duration":"120","day_long":"true    "}
    ]}

Then I'm parsing the ItemFileWriteStore to be Calendar store by the following code:

```
var cal_data = [];

var gotList = function(items, request){
    dojo.forEach(items, function(item){
      d_start = item.date_start[0].split('/');
      d_end = item.date_end[0].split('/');

      var dStart = new Date(parseInt(d_start[2]), (parseInt(d_start[1]) - 1), parseInt(d_start[0]), parseInt(item.start_hour[0]), parseInt(item.start_minute[0]), 0, 0);
      var dEnd = new Date(parseInt(d_end[2]), (parseInt(d_end[1]) - 1), parseInt(d_end[0]), 0, 0, 0, 0);

      var o = {
         id: item.id[0],
         summary: item.title[0],
         startTime:dStart,
         endTime:dEnd,
         calendar: item.type[0],
         allDay:(item.day_long[0] == "true" ? true : false)
      };

      //o.startTime=calendar.dateModule.add(o.startTime, "day", 1);
      o.startTime.setHours(parseInt(item.start_hour[0]));
      o.startTime.setMinutes(parseInt(item.start_minute[0]));
      o.endTime = calendar.dateModule.add(o.startTime, "minute", parseInt(item.duration[0]));

      console.log(o);

      cal_data.push(o);
    });
}

var gotError = function(error, request){
    console.log("The request to the store failed. ",  error);
}

TaskStore.fetch({
    onComplete: gotList,
    onError: gotError
});

calendar.set("store", new Observable(new Memory({data: cal_data})));
```

The console log for the above code shows:
Object
   allDay: false
   calendar: "visit"
   endTime: Fri Nov 02 2012 11:00:00 GMT+0200 (Jerusalem Standard Time)
   id: "3"
   startTime: Fri Nov 02 2012 09:00:00 GMT+0200 (Jerusalem Standard Time)
   summary: "Some Title One"
   **proto**: Object
   dashboard:124

Object
   allDay: true
   calendar: "visit"
   endTime: Tue Oct 23 2012 12:15:00 GMT+0200 (Jerusalem Standard Time)
   id: "4"
   startTime: Tue Oct 23 2012 10:15:00 GMT+0200 (Jerusalem Standard Time)
   summary: "Some Title Two"
   **proto**: Object
   dashboard:124

Everything seems good but still, the Calendar doesn't shows the items, why?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably call

calendar.set("store", new Observable(new Memory({data: cal_data})));

At the end of the goList method it should solve the issue?